# Error adding username, email and password in a mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I am trying to register users using php. Somehow, the only thing that gets put in is the ID. Mind giving me a tip?

```
 <?php
error_reporting(0);

require_once "php/connect.php";
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
$userpwd = $_POST ['userpwd'];
$userpwd2 = $_POST['userpwd2'];



    try {
        $statement = $dbconnection->prepare("INSERT INTO `tbl_Nutzerdaten` (userid, username, useremail, userpwd) VALUES (null , '$username', '$useremail', '$userpwd')");
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $fetch = $statement->fetch();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Fehler:" . $e->getMessage();

    }

?>
```

So this is what my insert.php looks like. I have been trying around to change my form up but still no success. The database has the table : "tbl_Nutzerdaten" with the columns userid,username,useremail and userpwd. Still i can not add anything except the ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Registrierung</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    require_once "insert.php";
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container bg-transparent border-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto border-0">
            <div class="img-thumbnail my-5 border-0">
                <img src="bilder/htl logo.png"></img>
                <div class="card card-signin my-5 border-0">
                    <div class="card-body border-0">

                        <form class="form-signin form-control border-0" action="#" method="post">
                          <div class="form-label-group">
                              <h1 class="text-center">Registrierung</h1>
                               <label for="username">Benutzername</label>
                               <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Benutzername" required autofocus>
                              <div class="form-label-group">
                              <label for="useremail">Email</label>
                              <input type="email" id="useremail" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                              </div>
                         </div>

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                                <label for="Passwort">Passwort</label>
                                <input type="password" id="userpwd" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Passwort" required>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-label-group">
                                <label for="Passwort2">Passwort bestätigen</label>
                                <input type="password" id="userpwd2" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Passwort bestätigen" required>

                            </div>


                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                             <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="pwcheck">
                             <label class="custom-control-label" for="pwcheck">Password merken?</label>
                            </div>
                          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase " type="submit">Registrieren</button>


                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the form i am using.

The only thing i see in the Database every time i fill out the form is a ID and empty values.
I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Form fields require the `name` attribute to pass data along.

Comment: **Warning!!!** Your code is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) **and** bind params. Using prepared statements and building your SQL as you do, is not efficient!

Comment: Thank you very much for the heads up. I will improve the code.

Comment: I haven't digged into your code, but tou have `error_reporting(0)` and you catch exceptions only to print the error message. That will prevent a lot of good PHP diagnostic information from reaching you.

Answer (score 0):

to send data to a specific PHP file you have to define where..

In HTML page in the form tag, the action attribute define the path to your file.php where to send the info.

for example:
`<form class="form-signin form-control border-0" action="path/to/your/file.php" method="post">`

In your input tags you have to add the "name" attribute, so you can refer to this data in your PHP file with this name... just to be clear with an example...

`<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Benutzername" required autofocus>`

and then in the PHP file take this data with something like this

`$username = $_POST ['username'];`

Then you have to send the data to a specific database, after all your controls on this data that you want..

To send the data you have to learn how avoid SQL injection with prepared statement, bind parameters and finally execute the statement.

I thinks you have to take a look to all this stuff, I suggest you to see this links:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms_attributes.asp